# Do I need to use WMI in order to merge text files in VBScript?

Tags: merge, vbscript, wmi

while searching for hints about merging text files in VBScript, I came accross this example: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Merge-multiple-txt-files-cbe9625c

```
Const ForReading = 1 

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objOutputFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("output.txt") 

strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set FileList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ 
    ("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_Directory.Name='z:\Scripts\Test'} Where " _ 
        & "ResultClass = CIM_DataFile") 

For Each objFile In FileList 
    Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objFile.Name, ForReading)  
    strText = objTextFile.ReadAll 
    objTextFile.Close 
    objOutputFile.WriteLine strText 
Next 

objOutputFile.Close
```

Instructions are just as follow:

> You can merge multiple txt files from specific folder to one txt file.
>   It will merge all data to one txt file. You dont need to copy data
>   manually. You can execute this script directly or from command promt. 
>   In this script you need to change the folder path from z:\Scripts\Test
>   to your existing path where all txt files are available as well as
>   change the name "output.txt"  with your require output file name and
>   path.

Although I'm quite new at VBScript (and didn't write VBScript for a *very very* long time), I don't get the point of using this WMI service for such a simple task (i.e. handling files in the same folder).

Wouldn't it be enough to just use `folder.Files` then filter the files to your need?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely right, using WMI for this task is silly.

This will do just fine, and it will be a lot faster, too:

```
Option Explicit

Dim FSO, OutputFile, File

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set OutputFile = FSO.CreateTextFile("output.txt")

For Each File In FSO.GetFolder("Z:\Scripts\Test").Files
    If LCase(FSO.GetExtensionName(File.Name)) = "txt" Then
        With FSO.OpenTextFile(File.Path)
            OutputFile.WriteLine .ReadAll
            .Close
        End With
    End If
Next

OutputFile.Close
```