# How to merge and delete files at the same time, starting with COPY /B?

Tags: cmd, merge, delete-file

After considering using VBScript to merge files - see [Do I need to use WMI in order to merge text files in VBScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56644998/do-i-need-to-use-wmi-in-order-to-merge-text-files-in-vbscript) - I finally ended up using the DOS command `COPY /B` with appropriate pattern (and matching file names/extensions).

Note: the `/B` flag prevents weird behaviour with EOL (diff. CR/LF/CRLF) & EOF (had some SUB char appearing) characters.

But now I wonder: is there a way to also delete the merged files at the same time, provided that the whole merge process succeeded (important)?

Either using the same command - but that seems unlikely, given the `COPY /?` help - or any another DOS command, in combination or in full replacement?

Comment: `copy /B "file1.ext" + "file2.ext" "merged.ext" && del "file1.ext" "file2.ext"`?

Comment: @aschipfl the thing is I have an unknown number of "fileX.ext"... (and with long filenames too) so basically I'm building my command string like `"COPY /B """ & long_file_name_variable & ".index.ext""" """ & long_file_name_variable & """.ext"`. I did this because I'm afraid the command string would be too long to be 1/ executed 2/ output for debug.

Comment: What about `copy /B "file*.ext" "merged.ext" && del /Q "file*.ext"` (given you really want to merge all files into a single one and the order does not matter)? Or you use a [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) to enumerate the files and use `copy` once per iteration...

Comment: The order **does** matter, but as I've constructed ever (partial) file name with a common prefix + an index + finally the same extension (e.g. `longfilename.001.ext`, `longfilename.002.ext`, & so on) I assume the COPY command sort them alphabetically before merging (and it works as espected).

Comment: Alright; it is the file system that returns the files sorted (like NTFS) or not (like FAT); to force alphabetic sorting you could do this: `set "FLAG=" & for /F "delims= eol=|" %F in ('dir /B /A:-D /O:NE "longfilename.*.ext"') do @(if defined FLAG (copy /B "merged.ext" + "%F" "merged.ext") else (set "FLAG=#" & copy /Y "%F" "merged.ext")) && del "%F"`

Comment: OK, then as the scripts are meant to be used on recent computers (Windows 10) there's not FAT involved. Thanks for your detailed answer anyway. Just a quick question about it: why do you `set` with double quotes *around* the equal sign?

Comment: `set "VAR=Value"` is the preferred syntax to set an environment variable, because it protects special characters (like `&`, for instance) and it avoids unintended trailing white-spaces; the quotation marks themselves do not become part of the value; note that this syntax requires the [command extensions](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) to be enabled (but this is the default setting anyway)...